# Command associate with button as default action none

Tags: codenameone

In a resource editor , by default action for button in command property is none for action .
So my action event for button is not working properly on clicked or selected . Anyone know how to set dynamic action as null or disable command action property on any button which has been created on resource theme in codenameone .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just fixed it . Just remove the set command button and add new button with the same UIID and don't click on any command , let it be null .